# Easier way to customize Spring Boot properties for a particular context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I have a project that uses a YAML with all default Boot properties with prefix `spring.jms.*`, `spring.activemq.*`... I'm moving it to a starter, so I need to isolate the needed configuration for my internal component from the defaults of the importer application.

Is there any way to nicely deal with this need? Ideally I can take profit transparently of the very same properties classes (`JmsConfiguration`, etc...) since they include the nested configurations. Perhaps in a way I have 2 blocks with `spring.jms` and such, and marking my properties as from a particular block.

I know profiles exist, but It feels weird to drive them from an optional component via starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

In the @Configuration:

```
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("custom.jms")
  public JmsProperties customJmsProperties(){
    return new JmsProperties();
  }
```

Anyway, after some discussions with Pivotal people, it seems like my need is probably a sign of a bad design